# Large number of inodes being used by Apache mod_cache_disk

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, inode

I am frequently getting to 100% inode usage on an Ubuntu PHP/Apache box.

The main usage seems to be in `/var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk`

Once every fortnight I have to manually remove files from this folder, this solves my issue.

`ls` in that directory returns the following

```
@  3  5  8  D  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
1  4  7  C  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
```

Why is this getting full, and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's getting full because Apache does not manage cleaning up the storage used by the disk cache.  That's why there is a bundled utility called `htcacheclean` to manage the size.

[htcacheclean official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htcacheclean.html)